# Triage Off-Topic Clarification

Tags: discussion, specific-question, triage, review-suspension

Why is this off topic? Seems like a basic question about joins, so maybe a duplicate?  After reading up on other bans, I know I shouldn't mark questions as Requires Editing, just trying to understand the other categorizations.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25591078

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's off-topic because the user does not provide enough details to identify a good answer. As noted in the comments, the provided tables do not provide a duration field, so it seems impossible to answer the question as it is currently posed.

(I will admit that when I was reviewing the question, I thought it looked okay at first glance, but when I read the comments, it became clearer to me that it had issues. My advice is to always read the comments fields and ofc avoid using Requires Editing.)

Comment: The select statements reference a Milliseconds column, and Name/Title columns that seem to be omitted from the table definitions.  If the table definitions included these columns, what should/would the question be marked as?

Comment: It might be a duplicate in that case, but I'd probably mark it as "Looks OK". The key idea here is that other users have to be able to reproduce the author's behavior so that those users can answer. I don't see any other glaring issues in the post.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what the close message looks like to people with 3k+ reputation:

[image]

For some reason, you have to be the question asker or have the Close Votes privilege to see the actual reason it was closed - as a comment suggested, the question can't be answered given the provided code.

I expect your confusion here is because the Stack Exchange network uses "off-topic" as a catch-all for all of the site-specific close reasons, so it encompasses both things that are actually off-topic and things that are potentially on-topic but unanswerable in their current state.

Comment: I have been using 'Needs details or clarity' as my catch-all, should I use 'off-topic' when I don't know where it belongs, but know it is unsalvageable?

Comment: There's a lot of overlap between the two, but I usually use off-topic > needs more information for when the question is clear but the code is missing or insufficient (or in an image), and needs details or clarity for when it isn't even clear what they're trying to ask.

Comment: And in these cases do you choose Blatantly off-topic in the off-topic drilldown?  Maybe this second set of choices is what's always steered me towards Needs details...